# Vertical margin between elements are lost in Bootstrap v3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m facing a problem with the new release of bootstrap 3.
Why vertical margin are lost between some elements in the new version? 
I´m migrating from v2.3, and now, a lot of things are going wrong.

In the example below, there is no margin between the panel and the form
This works fine in v2. Is there a workaround for this in v3?

```
<div class="container">     
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">   
        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeHolder="Search" type="text" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item No</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000</td>   
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *why* but you can fix this with :

```
.form-inline+.panel {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but I really want know WHY these margins are lost in the new version.

Comment: By the way, I don't see any bottom margin in `.form-inline` or inputs children in v2.3 and nothing in the "patch note". Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration